# How to run automatic monitor on my TP Link Deco M5 device?

Tags: home-networking, internet-connection

I'd like to automatically monitor (and save history) my internet connectivity speed on my TP Link Deco M5.
Any suggestions? Something like https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/faq/1462, or simple CLI command, which will send results to some cloud service.

Thanks, Vitaly